# SQL call for a scalar

Tags: c#, sql

When I work with `SqlDataAdapter`, I usually follow this pattern. Especially note the using/fill combination, which is basically a one-liner. The other stuff is just the facility around it.

```
private void PopulateData(DataTable table, long index)
{
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    commandText.Replace("{ID}", "" + index), Connection);

  using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    adapter.Fill(table);
}
```

Now, I'll be getting a number of scalars, so naturally I'm prone to use the appropriate method for that. However, I'm not certain how to make the code shorter without affecting readability.

```
private String GetString(long index)
{
  String output;
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, Connection))
  {
    command.Connection.Open();
    output = command.ExecuteScalar() as String;
    command.Connection.Close();
  }
  return output;
}
```

Preferably I'd like to get using/returning of the scalar value to be done as a one-liner too. Is it at all possible?

Or is the pattern of open-get-close inside the using-scope the best way to go? Perhaps it depends on the different circumstances? In such case - which?

Comment: Why do you care about the length of a method that's this short? Or are you planning to do this for every type you need?

Comment: @svick I'm going to have a single type only. And if that ever changes, I can go generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about the Private/Public scope of this method, someone else will have to talk about that.  but you can return inside a using statement, so instead of this:

```
private String GetString(long index)
{
  String output;
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, Connection))
  {
    command.Connection.Open();
    output = command.ExecuteScalar() as String;
    command.Connection.Close();
  }
  return output;
}
```

you would just return like this

```
private String GetString(long index)
{
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, Connection))
  {
    return (command.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
  }
}
```

The Command is automatically taken care of so you don't have to worry about explicitly disposing of it.

I assume that the connection is opened and closed by the piece of code that calls this private method, so I left out the connection open and close.

I am kind of on edge about doing it that way, but it seems like you would only want to open one connection for all the `SqlCommand`s that you need to run during the course of the application run.

Comment: [Disposing `SqlCommand` won't dispose the connection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60934/41071), so this code isn't the same as the original.

Comment: And [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) returns `object`, so the cast is necessary.

Comment: @svick, the connection isn't declared inside of this method, I assume that the connection `Connection` is taken care of outside of the method, so really the connection shouldn't even need to be opened here, the command should be able to be executed without the open command.

Comment: @svick, in that link for the disposing of the connection, the connection wasn't called using the connection method of the command either. I would think that this would change things a little bit because in OP's(Here) code the connection is created by the Command object and not a connection object, so disposing of the Command object should in theory dispose everything created by it.

Comment: “the connection is created by the Command object” No, it's not, it's created by some external code. You could claim that passing it into the constructor transfers ownership of the connection (streams often do something like that), but I guess that doesn't make sense here, since you can use a single connection for multiple commands.

Comment: @svick I see what you are saying.  you are right, the command is opening the connection, and it is separate still.

Comment: @Malachi I don't think it's going to work. One needs to open the connection first, right? Also, if I don't close the connection explicitly, will exiting the using's scope do that for me? Please note that your assumption on the connection being GCed elsewhere **is** correct (great mind think alike, right?) and it's only opening/closing I'm concerned about here.

Comment: the Command implements the IDisposable interface like a Connection object.  but you don't construct the connection object inside the private method, so I assume it is created and opened before you call this private method.  no need to open a connection twice, and you should close the connection after the call to the private method.  does that make sense, @KonradViltersten?

Comment: @Malachi Yes, it does. The way I resolved it, I **create** the connection elsewhere but I **open** and **close** it in the method. The reason for that is that the connection is going to be used several times during a longer time, so it needs to exist as a private property. However, it's not going to be actively used very much, just sitting there waiting, so I figured it's wiser to keep it closed and only open on demand. What do you think about that? I'm open for suggestions and critique.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, it all depends on your application. the way I suggest may not be the best way for you.

Answer (score 5):

Just continuation to @Malachi an here is a generic version of ExecuteScalar,

so it is good so you dont have to cast it again in code.

```
private T ExecuteScalar<T>(long index)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        var output = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (output != null)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(output, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return default(T);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think they are opening the connection outside of this method, so I don't think we need to worry about `using` the connection. so we probably don't need to open it either

Comment: yes good point editing it

Comment: Why using `Convert.ChangeType` instead of `as T`?

Comment: as T is only applicable for classes not for primitives type. private T ExecuteScalar<T>(object value) {return value as T; }This will throw the compliation error

Answer (score 4):

Since `Close()` is the same as `Dispose()`, you can use `using` on `Connection` too. This allows you to get rid of the `output` variable:

```
private string GetString()
{
    using (Connection)
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, Connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        return (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

I also changed `as` into a cast: if there is a mistake and `ExecuteScalar()` actually returns something that isn't a `string`, you want to know it right away clearly, not learn it later when you get a confusing `NullReferenceException`.

One more thing I changed is to use `var`: you can clearly see what the type is, you don't need to repeat it.

Comment: Is there a way to open the sucker inside the *using* head? It'd be great if I had only one statement to follow the innermost *using*. I'd skip the brackets, then, hehe. +1 for the first *using* and how simple that is. Never thought of not declaring the object inside there. However, I'm gravely aversed to *var* so I'll keep that. The cast is always to *String*, luckily. And I'll make it generic otherwise.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I guess you could write an extension method like `OpenAndReturn()` and then use `using (Connection.OpenAndReturn())`, but I don't think that would be a good idea.